# Space unwanted layout and image

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview

like the title said it there are some "space" before and after an image and i don't want it.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fond"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/top" 
        android:layout_gravity="top"        
    />

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/fond1"
        >



    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

So like you can see i have a first Layout with a background.
The ImageView is just after and should be on the top but it didn't.
The second Layout is to much after the image.
->

first layout

--unwanted space--

image

--unwanted space--

second layout

If anyone know how to delete this "space", thanks.

Comment: first you check image . i think there is problem in image. if is it possible then please upload image too ?

Comment: Are you sure your picture doesn't have a transparent space at its top?

Comment: i have a very slow internet i try to upload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` inside your `ImageView`. That way your `ImageView` will be adjusted to the provided image bounds.

Comment: There are no space with that but like you said it " this will not keep the aspect ratio of the image" and i need it do you know something who fit with what i looking for.

Comment: none of the  android:scaleType attribut are good for what i need.

Comment: @user1527152 Then i suggest you still use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but make your imageView to have the same aspect ratio as your image. Check the other values this tag may take in the link provided, if this does not suttisfy you. Also, as VinceFR suggested, check if your image has any trasparent space in its boundaries.

Comment: I haven't any trasparent space it's the first thing i check :) and i don't understand what you explain " Check the other values this tag may take in the link provided, if this does not suttisfy you" and how you do that : "imageView to have the same aspect ratio as your image" ?

Comment: @user1527152 Another solution that may work is to set your ImageView background to transparent. Something like this (inside your imageview): `android:background="@android:color/transparent" `.

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent" do nothing

Comment: @user1527152 Try setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` inside your ImageView. This is the last thing i know to adjust the bounds of your imageView to the image provided:S Hope that helps you out:)

Comment: i try to work it for hours i really happy but i have another thing who i don't undestand how to do

Comment: @user1527152 If i can help, i would gladly do. But in my opinion you better ask another question, so that other users may help you too.

Comment: @user1527152 I updated my answer with the correct aproach. You can accept it if you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690202/button-beyond-an-background-image this is my question. If you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout this Way::

```
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/fond"
   >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/top" 
    android:layout_gravity="top"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fond1"
    >
</LinearLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```