# Button beyond an background Image

Tags: android, android-layout

i think i don't find the correct word for the title so i will try to explain correctly.

So i have this image for a backround of my Layout :
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/fond1g.png/

And i would like to the button fit in it correctly.

Because there are some transparancy on the left and on the right.
So the button are beyond the sheet.

Is there something for say "Hey this is transparency and i don't want anything in it" ?
Or "Hey this is where (the sheet) i want to put everything ?

I tried to put another LinearLayout but i don't know how to give the good width.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `LinearLayout` you can set the background to your image. Then you can put anything inside the `LinearLayout` and everything will fit correctly inside your image.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="512dp"       
        android:background="@drawable/scaled"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"        
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I put my code. your answer doesn't help because the image have transparancy at the right and at the left so the button are on the transparancy area and i want them on the "sheet area" hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: yout edit his better. but Angelo do something who fits better with what i tried to do (it almost the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

From your question i understand that you want to avoid to put your buttons in your background image's left and right transparent edges. You can use the `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight` for this. For your code, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/fond"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/top" 
    android:layout_gravity="top" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fond1"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" <!--Use the correct dp value, i just use it for example -->
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" <!--Use the correct dp value, i just use it for example -->
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button_garçon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Bg"
            android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="actionGarçon"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button_mixte"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Bm"
            android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="actionMixte"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_fille"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Bf"
            android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="actionFille"           
        />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It fitcorrectly on the AVD but it will be ok on all the phone with this solution ?

Comment: @user1527152 It depends on the phone's resolution and screen size. But if you suply a satisfying dp value, i think you will be ok.

Comment: And i don't see it but it change the size of my buttons :/

Comment: Yes it will change the size (width) of your buttons since you use layout_weight in them. I think in your case it is something unavoidable. Btw, adding `android:layout_width="0dp"
` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in you buttons, i think, is better since you use weights in them.

Comment: I have tried some stuff and i think i will not have a better answer. So thanks for helping i have work all my afternoon on this 2 problems so now at 5:30pm i save everything and stop my work. thanks again.

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp" do the button with the size i want thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a symplify part of my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/fond"
   >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/top" 
        android:layout_gravity="top" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/fond1"
        >

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/button_garçon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Bg"
                android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="actionGarçon"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/button_mixte"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Bm"
                android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="actionMixte"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_fille"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Bf"
                android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:onClick="actionFille"           
            />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```